# Attribute error with BeautifulSoup get method

Tags: python, get, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a webscraper in Python using urllib and BeautifulSoup. My laptop works on Debian, so I don't use the latest version of urllib.

My goal is quite simple : extract values from a Wikipedia table [like this one](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_monuments_historiques_de_Chaumont).

So I started my script with :

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start ="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_monuments_historiques_de_Strasbourg"
url = urllib.urlopen(start).read()
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(url)

table = bsObj.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable"})
lines = table.findAll("tr")
```

Then, I used a for loop to scrap specific values from each row of the Wikipedia table :

```
for line in lines:
    longitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-longitude"})
    print(longitude)
    latitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-latitude"})
    print(latitude)
```

This gave for example :

```
<data class="p-longitude" value="7.764953">7° 45′ 54″ Est</data>
<data class="p-latitude" value="48.588848">48° 35′ 20″ Nord</data>
```

I thought that get() method would work fine, as :

```
longitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-longitude"}).get("value")
print(longitude)
```

But my terminal print this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper_monu_historiques_wikipedia.py", line 14, in <module>
longitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-longitude"}).get("value")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I didn't understand why, because my variables latitude and longitude are BeautifulSoup Tags (I checked with a type()), so the get methode should work...

Thanks in advance if you have the solution !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for line in lines:
    longitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-longitude"})
    print(longitude)
    latitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-latitude"})
    print(latitude)
```

For some of the lines, `longitude` and `latitude` are found, but for others the are not found, so they are set to `None`. You have to check whether it is found or not before performing any further operations, e.g.:

```
for line in lines:
    longitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-longitude"})
    latitude = line.find("data", {"class":"p-latitude"})
    if longitude and latitude:
        longitude_value = longitude.get('value')
        latitude_value = latitude.get('value')
        print(longitude_value, latitude_value)
```